# Historic (CAGR) of DJIA, S&P500, NASDAQ

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, historical-data, market-indexes

Looking for concrete data for a presentation I'll be giving about personal finance. I'm looking for the average market return of the three big indexes from 1950-onwards at least.

I've been able to locate the values for the S&P 500 at [MoneyChimp](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) which uses Robert Shiller's data that is a reputable source.

I'd be looking for something similar for the DJIA and NASDAQ (and any other world markets that could be of interest)

Comment: You could calculate it using data from [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/).

Comment: More details please: Must the source be free? What sort of granularity do you need, that is, do you merely want three data points for average market return for each of the 3 indexes in $USD from 1950 to now? Or do you want something exactly like what you got from the MoneyChimp url, but for the DJIA and NASDAQ too? If so, that's fine! Your question is reasonable, and I am not hostile :o) Please specify, as your question title asks for S&P500 info but your question may or may not, I am not certain.

Comment: @FeralOink - since he said similar to MC, I'm thinking annual total returns is what he seeks. Note - Money Chimp uses total return data, i.e. includes dividend return.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is get a good composite for a simple explanation of how, if the rate of total returns were to mirror the past 50 years into the next 50 years, what sort of return could we expect? I know the general rule is 6-8%, but I'm curious to have more concrete data from large indexes. The CAGR is the best measurement I could think of. The year doesn't necessarily need to be 1950, if it's not available, but I need something that I can cite as secondary research. I found the CAGR for the S&P, but would also like the DJIA and the NASDAQ. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd warn. The Nasdaq is not a broad based index. In the 2000 bubble, the Nasdaq shot up and dropped far more than the broader markets. It's tech heavy, and hasn't recovered to its old highs .